# Different behavior between rowid_to_column() and mutate(rowid = row_number())

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I can't understand why there is a different behavior between theses two pieces of code. When I run each chunk line by line, I can't really see the differences between the two data frame. Only the order of the variables is impacted. Could you explain me why I have this two different output ?

```
iris %>% 
  gather(var, value, -Species) %>%
  group_by(Species, var) %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  spread(Species, value) %>%
  select(-rowid)
```

```
   # A tibble: 600 x 4
   # Groups:   var [4]. 
   var          setosa versicolor virginica
   <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Sepal.Length    5.1         NA        NA
 2 Sepal.Length    4.9         NA        NA
 3 Sepal.Length    4.7         NA        NA
 4 Sepal.Length    4.6         NA        NA
 5 Sepal.Length    5           NA        NA
 6 Sepal.Length    5.4         NA        NA
 7 Sepal.Length    4.6         NA        NA
 8 Sepal.Length    5           NA        NA
 9 Sepal.Length    4.4         NA        NA
10 Sepal.Length    4.9         NA        NA
# … with 590 more rows
```

If I change `rowid_to_column()` to `mutate(rowid = row_number()`, I get a much shorter table, see below:

```
iris %>% 
  gather(var, value, -Species) %>%
  group_by(Species, var) %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  spread(Species, value) %>%
  select(-rowid)
```

```
# A tibble: 200 x 4
# Groups:   var [4]
   var          setosa versicolor virginica
   <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Petal.Length    1.4        4.7       6  
 2 Petal.Length    1.4        4.5       5.1
 3 Petal.Length    1.3        4.9       5.9
 4 Petal.Length    1.5        4         5.6
 5 Petal.Length    1.4        4.6       5.8
 6 Petal.Length    1.7        4.5       6.6
 7 Petal.Length    1.4        4.7       4.5
 8 Petal.Length    1.5        3.3       6.3
 9 Petal.Length    1.4        4.6       5.8
10 Petal.Length    1.5        3.9       6.1
# … with 190 more rows
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `row_number` works per group so gets 1:50 repeatedly. `rowid_to_column` ignores groups so get 1:600

Comment: you could add this as an answer @Richard